# How do you determine what startup programs steal focus and start ephemeral consoles?

Tags: troubleshooting, windows-8.1, boot

## Context

A startup program on my computer launches a short-lived `cmd.exe` on my desktop after logging in. The window steals focus and does not return it when it closes. It is too short-lived to read the text in the prompt. It is an extreme annoyance, because it increases effective startup time and hinders user experience.

## Problem

How do I determine what applications are starting `cmd.exe` and/or stealing focus on Windows startup/login?

*Note: The OS is Windows 8.1 Pro.*

Comment: Task manager lists all programs set to be launched when a user logs in

Comment: @Ramhound Are you implying that turning them off one-by-one and rebooting is the solution?

Comment: No; but you can determine what entries it might be

Answer (score 2):

## Alternate startup manager

While the Task Manager can give you *some* information about the startup items, if you want more control you can use a program like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx):

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and shows you the entries in the order Windows processes them. These programs include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. You can configure Autoruns to show other locations, including Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more.

It can be a starting point to collect and inspect possible candidates, discovering startup locations you may not be aware of.

## Pinpointing the issue

Since you know the short-lived process relies on the command line processor, you can temporarily override `cmd.exe` to prevent it from running, and analyze the command line parameters.

1. Log on with an administrator account.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit.exe` in the text box and press `Enter`.
3. Navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` registry key.
4. Right-click the `Image File Execution Options` subkey, choose **New > Key** from the context menu, and name it `cmd.exe`.
5. Right-click the empty area in the right pane and select **New > String Value**. Name the new value `Debugger`.
6. Double-click the `Debugger` value, and set it to `calc.exe`.
7. Restart Windows to ensure all startup items are loaded again. All `cmd.exe` processes will be redirected to the standard Calculator program.
8. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Task Manager.
9. Switch to the **Details** tab, right-click anywhere on the column header bar, and click on **Select columns**.
10. Enable the **Command Line** option, and click **OK**.
11. Check all `calc.exe` processes listed, and note down their command line parameters.
12. When you're done, delete the `cmd.exe` key you created in step 4.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You're just proposing an alternative way to disable startup items. OP is asking how do determine which items he should disable.

Comment: @gronostaj Not just an alternative way to disable some entries, rather a tool which can give the OP an in-depth knowledge of what gets started, and how. Something which the Windows built-in tools won't address completely. Anyway, I've since edited my answer to provide more food for thought.

Comment: Superb answer and nice trick getting windows to launch calc as a debugger, giving you time.